# LINQ not working

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, linq-to-objects

I’ve a class as :-

```
Class EmployeesList
{
    public string Category{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

And a `list<EmployeesList>` as `ListOfEmployee` :-

```
Category = “AA”  Name= “A”
Category = “AA”  Name= “B”
Category = “AA”  Name= “C”
Category = “AA”  Name= “D”
Category = “BB”  Name= “E”
Category = “BB”  Name= “F”    
Category = “CC”  Name= “G”
Category = “CC”  Name= “H”
Category = “CC”  Name= “I”
```

I’ve made two model classes

```
Class EmployeeModel
{
    public string EmployeeCategory(get;set;)
    public List<Employees> EmployeeList {get;set;}
}
Class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeName(get;set;)
    public int EmployeeID(get;set;)
}
```

My question is how can I make the `ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel>` from  `ListOfEmployee` using LINQ.

I tried this but not getting proper output.In this case the EmployeeList is always having first and redundant values. Please help.

```
var tables = ListOfEmployee
             .GroupBy(f => f. EmployeeCategory)    
             .Select(f => new Employee
                          {
                              EmployeeName = f.Key,
                              EmployeeList 
                                 = f.Select(g => new Employee 
                                                 { EmployeeName = f.First().Name}
                                            )
                                     .ToList()
                            }
                      )
             .ToList();
```

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var employees = ListOfEmployee
    .GroupBy(e => e.Category)
    .Select(g =>
        new EmployeeModel()
        {
            EmployeeCategory = g.Key,
            EmployeeList = g.Select(e =>
                new Employee()
                {
                    EmployeeName = e.Name,
                    EmployeeID = GetEmployeeID()
                }).ToList()
        });

return new ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel>(employees);
```

Comment: +1 I wanted to write the same, but was not quiet sure it it is really what OP wants. Also i would change the you constructor a bit to create Employee with IDs, like - 3-rd line: .Select((g,i) => , 7 line: EmployeeList = g.Select((e,j) => , and insert 1 line after 9th: EmployeeID = (i+j+1)

Comment: Yes, I left out the ID in case the OP had some other function to create it. I will edit my answer now